# При билде Android APP Budle сцены не загружаются

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play

Дело в том что при билде приложения для Play Market нужно билдить его как Android App bundle , но проблема в том , что при таком билде я просто не могу загружать сцены.
Когда идёт строка:

```
 SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
```

то экран становится черным(хоть сама игра работает (слышу звуки персонажей)

Раньше я задавал по этому схожий [конкурсный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014342/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-google-play) , но там был немного другой вопрос.

Comment: Вы уверены, что сцена **не загружается**? Черный экран может говорить об отсутствии камеры, черном изображении интерфейса поверх всего или, допустим, отсутствии освещения. Убедитесь, что проблема именно в сценах.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Я на 90% уверен что проблема с сценой.Персонаж звук которого я слышу появляется сразу на первой сцене , а препятствия на второй . При этом я слышал взаимодействия игрока(персонажа) c  "точкой" победы и ни разу с препятствием (я могу могу двигать персонажем) . Поэтому я могу предположить что препятствия просто не спавнятся и это означает что вторая сцена просто не загружается.

Comment: А грузить сцену по имени, а не номеру пробовали?

Comment: Вы пробовали подключать mLogCat, фильтровать по тегу Unity и смотреть чего выдаётся в консоль? Судя по вашему описанию - игра просто упала на выполнении какого-то метода.

Comment: @Александр Даниловский Нет,хотел так сделать и запустить как тестовую версию в Play Markete , но у меня начались проблемы с разрядностью(поэтому решил сначала решить эту проблему).

Comment: @M.Green Нет , сейчас попробую.